# Unity3d - Online multiplayer Turn

Tags: c#, android, iphone, unity-game-engine

Sorry for my English grammar :( (I try learn it)

I want to try write online turn based game with Unity3d.
I want that people will have login with their username and password and will can play from different device like :
1 player from android/iphone and second from facebook
or 1 from web - second from tablet
etc...
 Right now I think to create game 1 vs 1 (for 2 players) - but maybe in the feature I will open a new mode for multiplayer

it's simple to card game.

I'm c# developer so I will write code with c#.

My question is:

1) What I have to use for TURN BASED game (if you can give me link)
I think about WCF or WebAPI - for cross-platform
So what is best practice???

2) I want integrate a premium feature in the game - what you can suggest about billing system inside the game? With which company work is better?

3) I also can write code on JavaScript - if is give me plus in performance??

4) Authorization in the game:
What is best practice today? 
User have create account in my system or better to give to user login with his facebook account??

5) How I can sync. between mobile device and facebook game? if is possible?
Where I can save his credentials? If in mobile/tablet I can save in local database, in web - in cookie? where in facebook??

6) server - where the best place to publish the server side ? Amazon cloud? or not??

Comment: This is likely to get closed very quickly... This is all research that you should be doing yourself. If you have problems with a *specific* problem, let us know.

Comment: I do research, but i know here people have expressions with this question. So i wanted to know best practice.

Also If I understand right - Scene in unity3d its like 1 Page in web or 1 XAML in WPF?? I mean it is just View, right??

Comment: @David IMO... you raise very good questions that I for one would like to see discussion/answers on.  But.. it might be best to bounce this off of http://forum.unity3d.com/ as they'll probably be a bit more helpful regarding a big-picture question like this.  SO community gets all fussy when you ask 'direction' questions here.

Comment: @slumtrimpet - Ok, thank you. This is the link to same topic there, lets wait togeher where we will get good answers

http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/turn-base-game-c.349127/

Comment: @slumtrimpet good advice!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Unity itself supports networking. But there are other plugins like Photon Unity Networking which are enhanced version of unity networking. It also supports Turn based game plus it is a cross platform will support iOS, android and web. 
   [Photon Engine for Unity Networking](https://www.photonengine.com/en/PUN)
2. I assume by Billing System you mean In apps in the app. I have used UniBill its works fine with iOS,GPlay,Amazon etc stores. With so much less effort you can integrate the plugin. [Unibill by Outline Games](http://outlinegames.com/unibill-documentation/)
3. C# is enough i think.
4. You can use facebook it good enough. You can also add simple guest login for authorization. Guest will be registered on the basis of [Unique User ID](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SystemInfo-deviceUniqueIdentifier.html) which is provided by unity.
5. For storing data, you can use [Parse](https://parse.com/) Third party plugin. I have tried it and it works great. If you are going to web app as well then try using their Rest API. It will work will all their supported platforms.

Comment: WOW, man - thank you for this great answer. It was very helpful.

Comment: But what you suggest - to use Unity3d networking or to use photonengine?? just i have to pay of photonengine - and I dont know how much players will play in my game. It's more for get experience

Comment: I would suggest you to try photon because they have enhanced features like they have made like you dont have to create your own server,lobbies , rooms and random matchmaking. So you dont have to implement on that again using unity networking. I think 40k daily package suites your need for a start.https://www.photonengine.com/en/Turnbased/Pricing

Comment: Ok. Thank you. You help so much! Tommorow this question can be  bounty question and I will flag you answer))) Thank you again

Comment: 2 more question: 
1) if Photon is better choise?
2) Photon it is for rooms/lobbly only, right?? If yes - what is best practice for write server side where I can write business logic and work with database??
RESTAPI (ASP WebAPI) -- but.....if is it good from security side??
P.s If you can -write me your email (my twitter/linkedIn you can find in my profile)
thank you.

Comment: I think its a better choice. You dont have to write server side code. Read the documentation and see their example scenes. You will get the better understanding of how it works. If you have questions regarding photon you should better ask on their forums. They are very supportive. I told rest API is for parse not for photon unity networking (PUN). You have to write all on client side.

Answer (score 1):

Q1) What I have to use for TURN BASED game (if you can give me link) I think about WCF or WebAPI - for cross-platform So what is best practice???

---

WCF might not be the best choice, though it functions, but in typical cases, you might wish use [Socket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_socket) or [Websocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) to communicate.

The benefits of Websocket is that the connection, once established, remains active, and this is quite different from http protocols, in which request-response model is used. With http, the connection dismisses once the message is sent/received, you need to repeatedly setup the channel which has overheads if you have massive message, be it large in payload or frequency.

As a comparison shown below, the performance of Websocket is much better than http based communication, refer to [this link](http://blog.arungupta.me/rest-vs-websocket-comparison-benchmarks/) for more details.

### [image]

Another option is to use [Redis](http://redis.io/) or [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.org/), which has built-in support of the pub-sub model. Since you are talking about the card game, you might wish that:

- Player 1 flips the card, all the other players in this game/room can immediately see this change
- Player 2 does sth else, all the other players in this game/room can immediately see this change as well.

This is very simple if you use [Redis](http://redis.io/), one client publishes a message (e.g. card flip), then let all the other clients to subscribe this, then all other players (Android, iOS, web, facebook, tablet whatever) get notified immediately, it is then up to you implement your game logic.

---

The 3rd option is to use xxx-MQ (e.g. [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/), ZeroMQ, [MSMQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms711472%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), [ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/)) which are essentially message brokers, you can use the pub-sub model easily to implement the turn-based game logic.

---

Comment: We've used Socket.IO via Node.js with a Redis backend (layered between node and our backend server infrastructure) for stuff like this.  We use http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/best-http-released.200006/ for the socket.io magic and it works out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

> 3) I also can write code on JavaScript - if is give me plus in performance??

No really different.
[Here is performance test](http://dentedpixel.com/developer-diary/c-vs-unityscript-which-is-faster/)
Result is:

> The average of C# is 8,075ms and Unityscript is 8,142ms. So C# is a little bit ahead,

Comment: Ok, thank you. I saw this link - yes - I will write on c#